# How to update a record when cross-referencing another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Apologies if the title does not accurately describe the question (which it probably doesn't).  I have the following two tables :-

tLiveTable:

```
PieceID      LocationRef
------------------------
100              5
```

tPieceTable:

```
ID    BatchNo      PieceNumber
------------------------------
50    ABC          X1
100   ABC          X1
```

How can I update the LocationRef for that piece in tLiveTable given only the BatchNo and PieceNo?

I've tried the following:

```
UPDATE tLiveTable
SET LocationRef = 'blabla unimportant'
WHERE
PieceID = (SELECT ID FROM tPieceTable WHERE (BatchNo = 'ABC') AND (PieceNo = 'X1'))
```

But there can be multiple entries in tPieceTable with an identical BatchNo and PieceNo.  I want to only retrieve the ID from tPieceTable whose ID is currently the one in the tLiveTable.

Should I really be using an INNER JOIN for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will *not* work **as** `SELECT ID FROM tPieceTable WHERE (BatchNo = 'ABC') AND (PieceNo = 'X1')` **returns more than one ID**

Try this;

```
UPDATE L SET LocationRef = 'blabla unimportant'
FROM tLiveTable L JOIN tPieceTable P 
     ON L.PieceID = P.ID
WHERE (P.BatchNo = 'ABC') AND (P.PieceNo = 'X1')
```

Or using `IN` for `=`

```
UPDATE tLiveTable
SET LocationRef = 'blabla unimportant'
WHERE
PieceID IN (SELECT ID FROM tPieceTable WHERE (BatchNo = 'ABC') AND (PieceNo = 'X1'))
```